# How can I calculate V1 and V2 in this circuit?

Tags: voltage, amplifier

How can I calculate V1 and V2 in this circuit?

[image: schematic]

This is what I tried so far:

Calculate the voltage of R5 through voltage divider but I didn't  find the way, I was looking about second OA circuit but I don't really know what it does.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  Do you have a source or context for this circuit and are you sure it was transcribed correctly?  OA1 has positive feedback which is generally only seen in comparator circuits, and that's not what this looks like.  Note the "simulate this circuit" link below your schematic.  If you run a time domain simulation on it, you'll see how the circuit behaves, although CircuitLab assumes ideal op-amps, which can do things that real op-amps can't.

Comment: i already tried a simulation on proteus, results were the following:

Comment: The upper part is a voltage controlled current source. See at  [the bottom of this page](https://www.electrical4u.com/voltage-to-current-converter/). The bottom half looks like a [log amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_amplifier) but I am unsure.

Comment: For Vi = 1V, V1 = 3,47V and V2 = 5,55V

Answer (score 1):

#### Let's start with V2.

To determine **V2** you need to consider two cases:

1. Diode forward biased.
2. Diode reverse biased.

For **case 1**, there is negative feedback, so the V- input terminal of OA2 will be at 3V (or as near to it as the op-amp can get it), so:

**V2 = 3V + Vf**, where **Vf** is the forward voltage drop of the diode, ~0.6V (depending on the diode).

For **case 2**, OA2 is open loop, so V2 will swing towards one of the rails. Which rail is determined by considering the conditions required to make D1 reverse biased, V- input needs to be higher the V+ input, so V2 will swing towards the negative rail.

**V2 = -Vsupply + some voltage if the OA doesn't have rail-rail output**, this depends on the OA used.

#### Now to V1

The circuit around OA1 is a Howland Current Source (sometimes called a charge pump).

R5 is the resistor that the current is being controlled in.

Taking the case from OA2 where the diode is forward biased, it is reasonably easy to determine what V1 is. I've replaced the OA2 portion of the circuit with a fixed source. The direction of IL was chosen to match the direction of current flow when the diode is forward biased.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnvTud.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Applying KVL to node OA1-V+ we get:

\begin{gather*}
I_{1} +I_{2} +I_{L} =0\\
\\
I_{1} =\frac{V_{i} -V_{OA1-V+}}{R_{3}}\\
\\
I_{2} =\frac{V_{1} -V_{OA1-V+}}{R_{4}}\\
\\
I_{L} =\frac{3.0V-V_{OA1-V+}}{R_{5}}
\end{gather*}

We can relate Voa1-v+ to V1 because this voltage is governed by the non-inverting amplifier that is made up of R1 & R2 with Voa1-V+ as the input.

This is supported by the below, ignoring the non-linearities, the ratio of the V1 to OA1-V+ is 2.

[image: Relationship of V1 to OA V+ terminal]

For a non-inverting amplifier the output is:
\begin{equation*}
V_{out} =V_{in}\left( 1\ +\ \frac{R_{f}}{R_{1}}\right)
\end{equation*}

In our terms:
\begin{gather*}
V_{1} =V_{OA1-V+}\left( 1+\frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}}\right)\\
\\
R_{1} =R_{2} =R\\
\\
V_{1} =2V_{OA-V+}
\end{gather*}

Now, back to the KVL.

\begin{gather*}
\frac{V_{i} -V_{OA1-V+}}{R_{3}} +\frac{V_{1} -V_{OA1-V+}}{R_{4}} +\frac{3.0V-V_{OA1-V+}}{R_{5}} =0\\
\\
R_{3} =R_{4} =R\\
\\
\frac{V_{i} -2V_{OA1-V+} +V_{1}}{R} +\frac{3.0V-V_{OA1-V+}}{R_{5}} =0\\
\\
\frac{V_{i}}{R} +\frac{3.0V-V_{OA1-V+}}{R_{5}} =0\\
\\
Using\ V_{OA1-V+} =\frac{V_{1}}{2}\\
\\
\frac{V_{i}}{R} +\frac{3.0V-\frac{V_{1}}{2}}{R_{5}} =0\\
\\
This\ can\ be\ rearranged\ to\\
\\
\frac{V_{i}}{R} +\frac{6.0V-V_{1}}{2R_{5}} =0\\
\\
Solving\ for\ V_{1} \ and\ substituing\ our\ values\ we\ get:\\
\\
V_{1} =6V_{i} +6.0V\\
\\
\end{gather*}

This only applies when the diode is forward biased.

When the diode is reverse biased, for an ideal op-amp and an ideal diode, there should be no current through R5, however, diodes and op-amps aren't ideal, so there will be current, my LT spice simulation showed that the current follows the Howland Current Source output, which for this case is:

\begin{equation*}
I_{L} =\frac{V_{i}}{R_{3}} =\frac{V_{i}}{1k}
\end{equation*}

So the voltage that is developed at OA2-V- depends on the input circuitry of the op-amp and the leakage current of the diode.

This voltage is required to to be able to calculate V1 in terms of Vi.

Simulating the circuit with two different op-amps yielded different results for when the diode was reverse biased, however the results for when the diode is forward biased remained the same.

**Note**: In my simulations I used an AC source with amplitude of 1V for Vi.

[image: Circuit With OP07]

Note how V2 swings from ~3.6V to -negative rail.
For V1 when V2 is at ~3.6V, when Vi = -1, V1 = 0V, which is inline with the equation for V1 when the diode is forward biased.
When the diode is reverse biased, basically all bets are off.

[image: Signals of interest]

If the supply is increased to 20V the clipping that can be seen in the previous image goes away, and the current clearly follows the input with the gain 1 / 1000.

[image: Without clipping]

TLDR; Your question is not so straight forward to answer, and circuit analysis when you introduce non-linear components and non-ideal behaviours of components, can become quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I think second OA is a rectifier only ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_rectifier).

V2=3V in your case ( I think so..)

Comment: A principle characteristic of a precision rectifier is that feedback is taken from after the diode, which is not what's shown in the OP's circuit.